# Status bar Light content doesnot appear in Navigation Controller using Split view controller

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

When adding status bar as light content. its appearing fine in login screen. it changes to white in login screen. after successful login I have an split view and navigation controller.

I have added the code but still it shows black.

1) added below line in view contoller.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

2) info.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO
```

3) then came across this line and added this one also.

```
  controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
```

4) then came across article where it was mentioned to add extension if we need to change status bar in navigation but still nothing works

```
extension UINavigationController
{
    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        get {
            return .lightContent
        }
    }
}
```

I have added and tried with each of them but still it shows black status bar.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: no , not working. Its showing error   `Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'foregroundColor`

Comment: I added this line :     `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 18)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white`

But still nothing worked :(
            
        ]

Comment: @prateeksharma Which SWIFT version do you use?

Comment: @prateeksharma use this code : override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

Comment: see above its not working. The thing was that I'm trying to add this in Split view controller having individual Navigation controller. Its working fine for single view controller but not inside Split and navigation

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach to do the same.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

The idea behind this is that `UIBarStyle` figures out content color of `UIStatusBar`. Upon passing `.black` it figures out that background is black and `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` mode is required. And when you pass `.default` it figures out that background is light and returns black content or `UIStatusBarStyleDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

**I have the same problem with Navigation Controller.
But I resolve it as below.**

**Step 1:** Create a Custom Navigation class

```swift
import UIKit


class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.backgroundColor = .systemIndigo
        
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
}
```

**Step2:** Use this class to subclass your NavigationColtroller.

**Step3:** Go to your ViewController who is embedded with a navigation controller.

**Stpe4:** Put this line of code in viewDidLoad()

```
// MARK:-  Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
}
```

**Step5:** You can override a method in ViewController

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
      }
```

You are good to go. If you have any doubt plz comment