# Can't change color of status bar in a SplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

How can I change the color of the status bar when using a SplitViewController? When using just a viewcontroller with a navigationcontroller, the color of the status bar changes automatically by using ①. Are there any ways I can change the status bar automatically?

I want to add a dark mode to my app so, I can't change the status bar style from the project/target settings.

In my app I have a Notification that turns on and off my dark mode setting.

I have tried

①`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black`

②changing the info.plist

③[Status bar Light content doesnot appear in Navigation Controller using Split view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485347/status-bar-light-content-doesnot-appear-in-navigation-controller-using-split-vie)

This is what it looks like and I'm using ①to change the color of the navigationbar
[image]

Comment: Check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3  &   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042894/change-status-bar-color-dynamically-in-swift-4

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I've tried almost all of them but they don't work in a splitviewcontroller. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use extensions below. They get `preferredStatusBarStyle`
 from embedded ViewController. You need only override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in your custom ViewController

```
extension UISplitViewController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        let master = viewControllers.first
        return master?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
}

extension UITabBarController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return selectedViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question though, do I need to add this to all of my view controllers or just to the custom splitviewcontroller?

Comment: Works great on Master/Detail project using `UISplitViewController`, thanks!